# Implementing "Rename" from a ContextMenu 

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm

What is the best way to implement Rename functionality from a context menu in WPF?, What I want is functionality like Windows Explorer where you right click on an item, get a context menu, and if you select rename, the text becomes editable.

So far I've tried the following, but I think there must be a better way. Pretty much any aspect of this solution can be changed :)

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="0" MinWidth="200" MinHeight="75" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataSetsVM.DataSets, Source={StaticResource vmLocator}}" x:Name="dataSets">
<ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel x:Name="nameRoot">
            <TextBlock x:Name="nameBlock" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="200" Tag="{Binding DataContext, ElementName=dataSets}">
            <TextBlock.ContextMenu> 
                <ContextMenu >
                    <ContextMenu.Resources>
                        <Style TargetType="Image">
                            <Setter Property="Height" Value="24"/>
                            <Setter Property="Width" Value="24"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ContextMenu.Resources>
                    <MenuItem Header="Rename" x:Name="RenameDatasetContext"
                              Command="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag.CoreCommands.RenameDatasetCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ContextMenu}}"
                              CommandParameter="{Binding PlacementTarget.DataContext, 
                              RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                              AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}">
                        <MenuItem.Icon>
                            <Image Source="{StaticResource RenameLargeIcon}"/>
                        </MenuItem.Icon>
                    </MenuItem>
                </ContextMenu>
            </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
            </TextBlock>
            <TextBox x:Name="nameBox"  Text="{Binding Path=Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" MinWidth="200" Visibility="Collapsed" />
        </StackPanel>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>                                            
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=IsEditable}" Value="True">
                <Setter TargetName="nameBlock" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                <Setter TargetName="nameBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemTemplate> 
</ListBox>
```

The setter for Name does this:

```
set
{
    if (IsEditable)
    {
        IsEditable = false;   
        if (_name == value)
        {
            RaisePropertyChanged(NamePropertyName);
            return;
        }
        // Do some back end stuff
        if (back end stuff worked)
        {
            var oldValue = _name;
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(NamePropertyName);
        }
        else
        {
            // Do something about the error in the back end
        }
    }   
}
```

All the command does is set IsEditable to true.

This works unless you don't actually change the name, at which point there's nothing that sets IsEditable back as the setter for Name never gets called, so you can wind up with a bunch of items in Rename mode.

Can I set a property on a VM through a trigger, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Does IsEditable implements INotifyPropertyChanged?

Comment: Yes - as I said, it works until you start a rename and don't actually change the name :)

Answer (score 4):

this would be more MVVM-ish.. I simplified the binding to keep sample short and easy and I just hooked up the ViewModel to the cs. file in the back for quick test, all compiles/runs.

```
<Window x:Class="Sample.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    Height="350" Width="525" 
    x:Name="wnd">

<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ViewModel.Items, ElementName=wnd}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding ViewModel.SelectedItem, ElementName=wnd}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock x:Name="nameBlock" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="4">
                    <TextBlock.ContextMenu> 
                        <ContextMenu>
                            <MenuItem Header="Rename" 
                                      Command="{Binding EditItemCommand}">
                            </MenuItem>
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </TextBlock.ContextMenu>
                </TextBlock>
                <TextBox x:Name="nameBox" Text="{Binding Name}" Visibility="Collapsed" Margin="2,0"/>
            </StackPanel>
            <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsEditable}" Value="True">
                    <Setter TargetName="nameBlock" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                    <Setter TargetName="nameBox" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </DataTemplate.Triggers>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

code behind (note, view is completely passive):

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ViewModel ViewModel { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        ViewModel = new ViewModel();
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

viewModel (has all the manipulation logic):

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<SomeClass> _items;
    private SomeClass _selectedItem;

    public ViewModel()
    {
        SelectedItem = Items.First(); 
    }

    public ObservableCollection<SomeClass> Items
    {
        get
        {
            if (_items == null)
            {
                _items = new ObservableCollection<SomeClass>();
                for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) _items.Add(new SomeClass(string.Format("name {0}", i)));
            }

            return _items;
        }
    }

    public SomeClass SelectedItem
    {
        get { return _selectedItem; }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedItem == value)
                return;

            _selectedItem = value;

            foreach (var item in Items) item.IsEditable = false;

            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedItem");
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Model (completely dumb about other models, only knows how to set it's own behavior) with properties completely clean of any logic:

```
public class SomeClass : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _name;
    private bool _isEditable;
    private DelegateCommand _editItemCmd;

    public SomeClass(string name) { _name = name;}

    public DelegateCommand EditItemCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _editItemCmd ?? (_editItemCmd = new DelegateCommand(() => { IsEditable = true; }));
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            if (_name == value)
                return;
            _name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }

    public bool IsEditable
    {
        get { return _isEditable; }
        set
        {
            if(_isEditable == value)
                return;
            _isEditable = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("IsEditable");
        }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if(PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

Comment: Given this solution, how do you restore the previous visibilities of the textbox and textblock?

Comment: @user1722791: I added an InteractionTrigger to the text box

`<i:Interaction.Triggers>
                            <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
                                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding CancelEditNameCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
                            </i:EventTrigger>
                        </i:Interaction.Triggers>`

Answer (score 1):

this is weird but given your code (the way it's written) you're a in a funky situation, so the easiest/quickest solution is to reset all the ListBox items before starting to edit a new one:

in XAML added to nameBlock mousedown event:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="nameBlock" MouseDown="nameBlock_MouseDown"...
```

in cs code:

```
private object current;

private void nameBlock_MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (current != null && current == sender)
    return;
    foreach (var item in dataSets.ItemsSource)
        ((SomeClass)item).IsEditable = false;
}
```

also removed the IsEditable check from the setter

```
set
        {
            //if (IsEditable)
            {
                //IsEditable = false;
                if (_name == value)
                {
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
                    return;
                }
                // Do some back end stuff
                if (back //end stuff //worked)
                {
                    var oldValue = _name;
                    _name = value;
                    RaisePropertyChanged("Name");
                }
            }
```

Comment: I assumed that "dataSets" is your listbox's name, and "SomeClass" is the type to which you are binding the listbox items (the one that has Name and IsEditable properties)

Comment: I don't think the situation is funky, although I may have come up with some funky code trying to solve it. I'm open to suggestions that involve doing it a very different (but still MVVMish) way :)

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't mean to insult by "funky". To clarify, what I see is funky is using IsEditable state in the setter of the Name. I think if you remove IsEditabe check from there, things will clear up towards the solution. Besides, it is a useles check because you toggling textblock vs textbox already making it impossible to set the name when ISEditable is false.  It's a good puzzle, I'll play with it more :)

Comment: added a more MVVM-ish approach. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things.

First, if you are trying to get it to behave like Windows Explorer, then you should add a KeyBinding to Esc that sets IsEditable=false.

Second, you need to add a trigger on the TextBox for LostFocus that sets IsEditable=false.